# any fltk gui integrated compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, fltk

Well I have been stuck trying to successfully run code from "Stroustrup"'s book starting chapter 12, since I have tried everything to run it on windows visual studio 2015 I was wondering if I could somehow download a compiler which had all the *fltk + gui* things integrated on it so I could just straight start putting the code for the visuals, and if so what compiler would you recommend.

cheers

Comment: If you want to do that use codeblocks.

Comment: @cup I'm on it, so rltk is already integrated on the normal setup version? thx by the way

Comment: downloaded codeblocks and i have to say its way harder than visual studio, didnt even mange to debug

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no such a compiler.
What you can use is the FLUID tool, that comes with FTLK (you must compile it). This tool allows for building GUI's in a rather visual way and generates the C++ code.
This is the official documentation: http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/fluid.html

You can also find tutorials on youtube